# For a numpy array, is there a difference between assigning to array and array[:]?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This a quite basic and subtle question that I've never considered before, but I recently stumbled across the notation `a[:]` again and this time it caught my attention. Consider the two following examples:

**Example A**

```
a     = numpy.zeros(10)
vals  = numpy.arange(10)
a     = vals**2
```

**Example B**

```
a     = numpy.zeros(10)
vals  = numpy.arange(10)
a[:]  = vals**2
```

The difference is solely in the assignment in the last line. For years I've never thought about the difference between the two. But is there a difference? Does B use less memory by directly assigning the values to the existing array vs. creating another temporary array in example A? Or are the two identical after all (even under the hood)?

Comment: `a  = vals**2` isn't "assigning to array".  It's assigning an array to a variable.  The fact that `a` was already assigned to an array doesn't make a difference.  All the 3 assignments in that first group do the same thing.

Comment: I suggest you read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html Note, simple assignment, `a = b` *always works the same way*, it is a feature of the Python *language*. On the other hand, `a[whatever] = something` is essentially sugar for `a.__setitem__(whatever, something)`, so it is technically up to the *type* to determine the semantics. Assignment, on the other hand, *always* simply assigns an object to a name (or a target list of names) in some particular namespace. It *never* mutates.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I must say I almost like your comment-answer best. Would you be interested in turning it into an answer that I could accept?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Never? The assignment `a = b` can [mutate `b`](https://tio.run/##ZYwxCgIxEEX7OcV0m4BYuBayYLXHEAkZM9GFODskaTx9zCpWvubB5/H1VR@rjCfNrd2SLwXnCbATOKJzgZNzpnCK9jtv0N6rsgRzPFgAj2ecjQXqvlwBNC9SzUAc18zYH5e7PFnqNOyQ7CenX4Q@Vs5/UWtv) :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy That is some evil black magic, leading me to conclude that whoever uses code like that in practice is a witch, in all of its meanings.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the difference is that `a =`  changes the value associated with the name `a` and `a[:] =`  internally mutates `a`.

Mutating `a[:]` internally should take up a little less memory, since the original value of `a` doesn't need to be separately garbage collected after the assignment (as no names point to it anymore).

This also stands for other Python objects, collections, etc, that support slice assignment (and in fact, the fact the same object is modified  has an important use case with [filtering directories in `os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)).

However, your use case will probably be best served with just

```
a = numpy.arange(10)  # (or however you'd get the values to square)
a **= 2
```

since Numpy can optimize the [`__ipow__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ipow__) inline power operation to happen all in-place and there would be no additional allocation for `vals ** 2` before it's put in its place.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my guess about what's happening. For N=10 the difference will of course be negligible, but if the arrays are MB or GB large, I guess it could sometimes make a difference. Also, thanks for the hint about the in-place manipulation, but of course the squaring was just a MWE.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the "less memory". Yes, their second code doesn't need to garbage collects the old array `a`, but it garbage collects `vals**2`, which their first code doesn't. Isn't that equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Result of the first:

```
[ 0  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
```

Result of the second:

```
[ 0.  1.  4.  9. 16. 25. 36. 49. 64. 81.]
```

Do those really look identical to you?

Assigning into an existing array keeps its `dtype`. Assigning just to the variable instead gets you whatever the new value has.

Also, if you had another reference to the original array, i.e., let's say you had done `b = a`, then your first code won't affect `b` at all while your second code will.

Comment: Oh, that was actually unintended. I momentarily forgot that arange creates int arrays, leading to type conversion. Your last point is also quite interesting, so essentially `b = a` prevents the garbage collector from removing the (content of the) old `a` upon its reassignment.

Comment: Choose the more robust approach.  Don't try to micro manage memory usage.